# NEW y OLD variables postgres

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql

Tengo el siguiente problema, necesito hacer una bitacora y que por cada dato modificado cree un registro en la bd.

Cada tabla tiene un trigger que llamara a la funcion bitacora() y dentro de ella debo capturar los OLD y NEW y hacer un ciclo para que por cada dato modificado se agregue un registro en old_value y new_value respectivamente.

Tengo un While que ya hacer el ciclo y ya obtengo todos los campos de la tabla, el problema es que a cada paso del ciclo lo guardo en la variable Campo. No se como hacer para que al registrar en la bitacora me tome NEW.Campo y agarre el valor que tiene Campo y no literalmente 'Campo'.

En otros lenguajes hay funciones para que tome el valor de la variable y no el nombre como tal, hay algo parecido en SQL? Sino que solucion me proponen? Gracias de antemano

```
CREATE FUNCTION bitacora() RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE Usuario INT;
    Tabla VARCHAR(100):= TG_TABLE_NAME;
    Operacion VARCHAR(50) := TG_OP;
    Campo VARCHAR(100);
    Old_value VARCHAR(100);
    New_value VARCHAR(100);
    Fecha TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE := NOW();

    Field INT := 0;
    MaxField INT := MAX(ORDINAL_POSITION)
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = Tabla;
BEGIN
    Usuario := get_sesion( pg_backend_pid() );
    WHILE Field < MaxField LOOP
        SELECT MIN(ORDINAL_POSITION) INTO Field
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE TABLE_NAME = Tabla AND ORDINAL_POSITION > Field;

            SELECT COLUMN_NAME INTO Campo
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                WHERE TABLE_NAME = Tabla AND ORDINAL_POSITION = Field;
        IF OLD.Campo <> NEW.Campo THEN // Aqui el problema.
        // necesito que campo se sustituya por el valor de la varible.
        // no que busque Campo en NEW o OLD porque no existe ese campo.
            INSERT INTO
                bitacora (
                    idusuario,
                    tabla,
                    campo,
                    operacion,
                    old_value,
                    new_value,
                    fecha
                ) VALUES (
                    Usuario,
                    Tabla,
                    Campo,
                    Operacion,
                    cast(OLD.Campo AS VARCHAR(100)),
                    cast(NEW.Campo AS VARCHAR(100)),
                    Fecha
                );
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
```

Answer (score 1):

He logrado terminar la bitácora y quedo de la forma en que quería, que funcione con todas las tablas que yo necesite y simplemente haga un llamado con un trigger, a los que les interese les dejo el enlace aquí: https://bitbucket.org/snippets/eliasjtg/8o5MoA/bitacora-postgresql

Answer (score 0):

A ver, no controlo NADA de postgre, pero veo que tampoco es tan distinto. Entonces te voy a comentar algunas cosas que veo que me rechinan un poco, por si alguna te pudiera ayudar.

En VALUES, está correcta esa sintaxis? Si quieres meter la variable, no deberías usar @campo ? (digo @ porque creo recordar que así era en mysql). Ya te digo que te voy dando ideas, no soy experto xD. Eso y especificar el tipo ahí de nuevo cuando veo que has hecho el DECLARE arriba. Además tienes una variable llamada Campo y un campo llamado campo xD. Usa tabla.campo para especificar también.

Otra cosa que veo rara, es por qué comparas valores old y new de la variable en el IF. En todo caso, deberías hacerlo sobre COLUMN_NAME, no ?

Y la última, es que donde pones COLUMN_NAME te refieres a el dato, o estás intentando meter el nombre de la columna ?

Ya te digo, no estoy muy puesto en esto, así que me vas diciendo si me equivoco o te ayudo en algo y así aprendo yo también :)

Comment: - Lo que dices del @Campo, lo vi por internet desde que empece a hacer esto y no, no funciona, el INTO Campo si funciona.

"Eso y especificar el tipo ahí de nuevo cuando veo que has hecho el DECLARE arriba. Además tienes una variable llamada Campo y un campo llamado campo xD. Usa tabla.campo para especificar también."

No existe en mis tablas ningun campo llamado Campo, Campo es una variable que he creado para que en el ciclo recorra los campos y poder crear un registro por cada uno.

- Comparo el Old y New para que si no hubo ningun cambio no cree un registro innecesario.

...

Comment: Y por ultimo, ahi en COLUMN_NAME estoy haciendo una consulta para obtener el nombre de la columna y asignarla a Campo.

Comment: Ok, leído esto y leído que lo has solucionado, me alegro :)